# Obscure show or movie from the 80's or 90's

Tags: story-identification, powers

Because I watched this when I was so young, I might have meld two shows into one.

- these people have white jewels in the center of their fore heads
- to activate their powers, they place their index & middle fingers on their temples.
- I think they would glow as well
- I also remember a white, teenage girl with long brown hair as one of the main leads

Comment: What powers did they activate?

Comment: Is this a cartoon or a live action show?

Comment: I can't remember their powers. @richard

Comment: It was live action @e.z.hart

Comment: http://p3.storage.canalblog.com/31/44/73865/8924953.jpg

Comment: @richard YES!!!

Comment: @vonClarkson - Assuming that's a yes, I've added it as an answer.

Comment: see OP confirmation comment above

Answer (score 6):

This is [The Girl from Tomorrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_from_Tomorrow), an Australian TV series from 1991. The title character, Alana (played by Katharine Cullen) has a headband with a prominent white jewel set into it which she can activate in order to use an ill-defined variety of telepathic and telekinetic powers.

When her '[transducer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_from_Tomorrow#The_transducer)' is activated, either by thought or by touching the rim, it would glow and project a visible beam of energy.

[image]